# Esper - handling random sequence of events with the followed by pattern -->

Tags: esper

We have two types of events - InventoryEvent(Order) and InventoryEvent(Cancel).
I want to track order events that are not followed by Cancel events within 6 secs.
This is the query being used

```
select a as InventoryEvent from pattern ["
                + " every a=InventoryEvent(system='Order') -> "
                + "("
                 + "(timer:interval("
                 + intervalSecs
                 + " sec) and "
                + " not InventoryEvent(system='Cancel',keyValue('MessageKey')=a.keyValue('MessageKey')))"
                + ")]
```

The time interval is 6 secs and the Order event and the Cancel Event are joined by a common message key(order id)

This works very well in most cases as below

- Order Events(id1) --> Cancel Event(id1) >6 secs
- Order Events(id1) --> Cancel Event(id1) <6 secs
- Order Events(id1) not --> Cancel Event in 6 secs
- Multiple Order Events followed by Cancel Events

Now we have scenarios where we cannot gurantee the order in which the order and cancel events come through. So we have a case

- OE(id1) -->(**6secs**) OE(id2) -->(6secs) CE(id1) -->(6secs) CE(id2).

Basically two order events followed by two cancel events with a 6 secs interval. This also works.
Now we change the time of the second order event to be 4 secs instead of 6 secs,

- OE(id1) -->(**4secs**) OE(id2) -->(6secs) CE(id1) -->(6secs) CE(id2).

It does not fail for the second order event. Not sure what we are missing in terms of the query.

Does anyone have an idea why?

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot guarantee the order, use a join instead or reorder events (there is a reorder view that helps).
The first scenario will also not pattern match for id1, submit a test case to the user mailing list if you think otherwise.